# Close container with a key event

Tags: jquery

i have a lot of containers in my page, the user want to be able to close then using the ESC key.

is there any dynamic way to identify what containers its first ( like, highest z-index ), in case that i have more then one opened?

the way i'm doing this its very funny/ugly.

i'm reinvented the wheel, i think .

my js:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) { 
    if (e.which == 27) {

        if($("#container1").css("display") == "block"){
                // this is a sub-container inside the container1
                if($("#subContainer1").css("display") == "block"){
                    $("#subContainer1").fadeOut();
                }else{
                    $("#container1").stop(true,true).fadeOut('fast');
                }

        }else if($("#container2").css("display") == "block"){
               // this is a sub-container inside the container2
                if($('#subContainer2').css("display") == "block"){
                    $("#subContainer2").fadeOut();
                }else{
                    $("#container2").stop(true,true).fadeOut('fast');
                }
        }
    }
});
```

have any other intelligent way to do this ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made some change's:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) { 
    if (e.which == 27) {

        eventHold = null;
        $('.escSuporKey').each(function(){
           thisdisplay = $(this).css('display');
           if(thisdisplay === "block") {
               eventHold = $(this);
           }
        });
        eventHold.fadeOut() // or whatever
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Search through all of the containers. Find the one with the highest z-index. Hide that one when the keydown event fires.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) { 
    if (e.which == 27) {

        zindex = 0;
        zelem = null;

        $('.container').each(function(){
           thisindex = $(this).css('z-index');
           if(thisindex > zindex) {
               zindex = thisindex;
               zelem = $(this);
           }
        });

        zelem.hide() // or whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: testing, just close the ) of bind ;)

Comment: the function hide the first time, but the second dos not.

Comment: the each runns all container class getting the z-index of each one, if he find the highest , and this highest are hidden ?